# Simultaneous/Combined MouseListener & KeyListener, MouseEvent & KeyEvent Java

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, macos-sierra, keyevent

I want to know how work Simultaneously a *MouseEvent* & *KeyEvent*.

Suppose an JFrame, JPanel.

I want to know how work with an Event when certain *MouseEvent* & *KeyEvent* example:

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
  @Override public void keyReleased( KeyEvent evt) {
    if ((evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_META) || (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS)) {
      //SomeEVENT
    }
  }
});

addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {
    if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(evt)) {
      System.out.println("Left button released.");
    }
  }
});
```

**TEST CODE**:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("mouseClicked:");
    if ((evt.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.VK_META) == KeyEvent.VK_META) {
      System.out.println("KeyEvent.VK_META:");
    }
    if ((evt.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL) == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL) {
      System.out.println("KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL:");
    }
    System.out.println("KeyEvent.getKeyModifiersText(evt.getModifiers()):" 
        + KeyEvent.getKeyModifiersText(evt.getModifiers()));

  }
});
```

**Output**

```
mouseClicked:
mouseClicked:
mouseClicked:
mouseClicked:
mouseClicked:
```

The problem the Button Control is not detected!!!

But **How perform the action only when simultaneosly LeftButton + <kbd>CMD</kbd> or <kbd>WIN</kbd>?**

**EDIT2**

Using my before **TEST CODE** and Pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click, the Message is shown!!!

```
mouseClicked:
KeyEvent.getKeyModifiersText(evt.getModifiers()):⌥+Button1
mouseClicked:
KeyEvent.getKeyModifiersText(evt.getModifiers()):⌘+Button1
mouseClicked:
KeyEvent.getKeyModifiersText(evt.getModifiers()):⌃+Button1
mouseClicked:
KeyEvent.getKeyModifiersText(evt.getModifiers()):⌘+⌥+Button1
mouseClicked:
KeyEvent.getKeyModifiersText(evt.getModifiers()):⌘+⌥+Button1
mouseClicked:
KeyEvent.getKeyModifiersText(evt.getModifiers()):⌥+Button1
mouseClicked:
KeyEvent.getKeyModifiersText(evt.getModifiers()):⌘+⌥+Button1
mouseClicked:
KeyEvent.getKeyModifiersText(evt.getModifiers()):Button1
mouseClicked:
KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL:
KeyEvent.getKeyModifiersText(evt.getModifiers()):⇧+Button1
```

Is it a OS Problem (I have macOS *Sierra*)?

Comment: `MouseEvent` has support key the extended key strokes (alt, ctrl, meta, shift)

Comment: Check out the example shown in the [JavaDocs for `MouseEvent#getModifiersEx`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getModifiersEx--)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for the info, but I can't understand why is not working.

Comment: The do some googling. Also, look at the MouseEvent JavaDocs, in particular things like isControlDown, all the answers are there

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a simple as reading the [JavaDocs for `MouseEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html)

The `MouseEvent` carries with it an [Extended Modifier state](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getModifiersEx--) which is a simple bit mask of the buttons and keys which were used to generate the event.  There are plenty of examples about of how to make use of them.

Because I'm both stupid and lazy, I just prefer to use the functionality provided by the event object itself, like [`MouseEvent#isControlDown`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#isControlDown--) and [`MouseEvent#isMetaDown`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#isMetaDown--)